# How to handle JSON response in Nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, json, nightmare

Interested to know if there is a better or another way to handle URLs that contain only JSON data **using Nightmare.js** than using `document.querySelector('*').textContent` within .evaluate?

Here is an example; the external URL here contains the following which is the contents of a linked select field

```
{
  "baseDeliveryModelId":1,
  "county": [
     {"id": "1000706000", "label": "Çukurova", "value": "Çukurova"},
     {"id": "1000707000", "label": "Sarıçam", "value": "Sarıçam" },
     {"id": "1000922000", "label": "Seyhan", "value": "Seyhan"}, 
     {"id": "1000921000", "label": "Yüreğir","value": "Yüreğir"}
  ], 
  "listType":"DISTRICT_LIST"
}
```

A sample.js code to retrieve just the county data from the URL *(which works fine)*

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
    vo = require('vo'),
    nightmare = Nightmare({show: true});


function counties(city) {
    let countyUrl = `https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/getCityDeliveryLocation.do?shopId=1&locationId=${city}&locationType=city&deliveryTypeId=0`;
    return nightmare
        .goto(countyUrl)
        .evaluate(function() {
            return (JSON.parse(document.querySelector('*').textContent)).county;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Error: ', err);
        });
}


vo(function* () {    
    return yield counties('01');    
})((err, result) => {    
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(result);    
});
```

Note: The question is about using **Nightmare.js**, or using other libraries **with Nightmare.js** in node.js for handling JSON responses, I am fully aware and capable of using other libraries such as axios.js on their own to solve the above.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal: Do you know what nightmare.js is? Without something like nightmare.js you cannot do ajax calls. On the other hand if you just want the JSON data you don't need to do ajax if you can simply do a http request.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal: Without something like nightmare.js you can't really use jquery because jquery doesn't work on node.js. You CAN use jquery in nightmare though.

Comment: @Zerka Mari is there a reason why you need nightmarejs for this, you can accomplish the same thing with an http request?

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal the question is if there is a better way to handle JSON using nightmare.js.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it, it's faster to implement, easier to remember. We can use it like this until someone creates functions like  **.text()** and **.json()**.

```
// Initiate nightmare instance
var nightmare = Nightmare({
                show: true,
                alwaysOnTop: false
            })
            // go to a page with json response
            .goto('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
            .evaluate(() => {
                // since all of the text is just json, get the text and parse as json, return it.
                return JSON.parse(document.body.innerText)
            })
            .then((data) => {
             // then use it however we want
                console.log(data)
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need nightmarejs. 
if you can use a library that auto parse the json response for you, for example request-promise

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

rp({
url: 'https://www.sanalmarket.com.tr/kweb/getCityDeliveryLocation.do?shopId=1&locationId=${city}&locationType=city&deliveryTypeId=0',
json: true
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.country);
})
.catch(function (err) {
    // Crawling failed...
});
```

Comment: The question isn't if I need or don't need nightmare.js, it is if there is a better way to handle JSON using nightmare.js. I am fully aware of other libraries and use them on other projects one is the one you've mentioned another is axios.